# Why is RMSProp considered "leaky"?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, gradient

```
decay_rate = 0.99 # decay factor for RMSProp leaky sum of grad^2
```

I'm perplexed by the wording of comments like the above where they talk about a "leaky" sum of squares for the RMSProp optimizer. So far I've been able to uncover that this particular line is copy-pasta'd from Andrej Karpathy's [*Deep Reinforcement Learning: Pong from Pixels*](https://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/), and that RMSProp is an [unpublished optimizer proposed by Hinton in one of his Coursera Classes](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#rmsprop). Looking at the math for RMSProp from [link 2](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#rmsprop), it's hard to figure out how any of this is "leaky."

Would anyone happen to know why RMSProp is described this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RMsprop keeps the exponentialy decaying average of squared gradients. Wording (however unfortunate) of "leaky" refers to the fact how much of the previous estimate "leaks" to the current one, since

```
E[g^2]_t := 0.99 E[g^2]_{t-1} + 0.01 g^2_t
            \_______________/   \________/
               "leaking"         new data
```